# TCP FIN behaviour when overwriting tcp segment

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, network-programming, protocols

While going through an open source code-base, I was thinking of an interesting scenario. Lets say after the successful TCP connection establishment , A TCP client sends a packet with sequence number = 101,len=100. Server is yet to receive data from client with seq=1, len=100. 
After that client sends a FIN with sequence number 151. Now that the TCP server thinks FIN as retransmission. My question is what should be the behavior of a TCP end point according to RFC, if a server receives a FIN packet, which overwrites a TCP segment.
Will the FIN be processed, discarded or depends on TCP implementation ?

Comment: I would say it isn't defined. The RFC isn't really concerned with incorrect behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

> Will the FIN be processed, discarded or depends on TCP implementation ?

This is a special case of overlapping segments, i.e. where the server receives first one segment and later another segment which has a start inside the first segment. Most implementations will consider the later segment invalid but like @EJP already commented the RFC's are usually not concerned defining behavior for invalid data.

In any way segment overlapping or similar invalid data can often be used to bypass firewalls between client and server, because these firewalls either don't keep enough state to filter out invalid data (because state needs resources which slows down the firewall) or simply show a behavior differently to client and server when handling invalid data.

Answer (score 1):

This question is very similar to one I responded 4 weeks ago. If not equal. I think the response is the same in both threads. Please take a look also at @EJP's comments in that thread which are also relevant to your question.
[out of order FIN packet and overwrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31261519/out-of-order-fin-packet-and-overwrite/31273148#31273148)

Comment: Agreed, it is defined, I am crazy.